# Javascript Date valueOf equivalent in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, datetime

Is there any equivalent of Javascript `new Date().valueOf()` in C#?

I tried using `DateTime.Now.Ticks` in c#, but both are different.

I need this because, I'm writing some `serverless aws lambda code` where they are supporting both `nodeJs` and `C#` code.

So, I don't want to get any conflict with datetime in future.

In future, I may query on the datetime values.

Comment: https://forums.asp.net/t/2033496.aspx?Convert+objectdotTicks+of+C+to+equivalent+date+value+in+javascript

Comment: Check utcnow.ticks, both should ideally be same

Comment: FWIW `new Date().valueOf()` is the equivalent to `Date.now()`

Comment: In case you didn't notice, Tim realized his answer was wrong. The answer in the dupetarget is correct. (He's also fixed his answer.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`new Date().valueOf`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_valueof_date.asp) returns the millis since january 1, 1970 UTC, you can use this C# code:

```
DateTime startDt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
TimeSpan timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow - startDt;
long millis = (long)timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds;
```

Comment: @Tim : Do I need to use `DateTime.Now- startDt` or `DateTime.UtcNow- startDt`. because the original post is showing based on `UTC`

Comment: @RealSteel: By accepting this answer, you've made it impossible for Tim to delete it and instead post it on the dupetarget.

Comment: Oh, I didn't knew this :(

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I just tried it and it seems that using `UtcNow` **is** correct, which I find surprising. When I do the above, I get an answer that's an hour off (I'm on British Summer Time).

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I tested the result against the value I get from `Date.now()` on a browser. It's definitely an hour off (and isn't when I use `UtcNow`). I don't yet understand *why*, but it's quite clear.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: i see, i have overloooked in my link that it's the number of millis since 1970 but in UTC. Then it's `DateTime.UtcNow`

Comment: This is now just a duplicate of the answer on the dupetarget.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: cannot delete

Comment: :-) Quite true.